# Ignoring the unneeded

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

In the watched tags how can I ignore the questions with accepted answers so, in the least, they do not show like ignored tags do not show?

Answer (score 7):

There is currently no way to filter out questions that have only accepted answers from the usual questions lists (as opposed to having either accepted or *upvoted* answers as in [TheSimpliFire's answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/28905)).

However [search](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching) has the `hasaccepted:yes/no` parameter which will show questions either with an accepted answer, or without an accepted answer, depending on `yes` or `no`.  Adding a tag search parameter (*e.g.*, `[calculus]`) will filter that to questions with that tag. Also, the `intags:mine` parameter returns posts tagged with a tag you are watching (and not with a tag you are ignoring).

Here are a couple of examples:

- [`[calculus] hasaccepted:no`](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcalculus%5D+hasaccepted%3Ano) returns all questions in the [calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus) tag which do not have an accepted answer.
- [`intags:mine hasaccepted:no`](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=intags%3Amine+hasaccepted%3Ano) will return all question in tags that you are watching (but have no tag you are ignoring) which have no accepted answer.

---

I should note that Stack Exchange is working on something capable of this: [Custom question lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312781).  It is right now in [alpha testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313940), but only on Stack Overflow, its Meta, and Meta Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

There is already that feature.

For example, I am watching the [calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus) tag at the moment and if I click into it, I get this:

[image]

The heading says '12,990 questions with no *upvoted or accepted* answers'.

Comment: Here we have violations of simple engineering rules - KISS, "keep it simple stupid" and if is not broke do not fix it.  In addition I have not found a usable manual or context sensitive help for an over complicated design.  I have seen some updates that were wonderful and documented.  Modern updates, for what little they add, actually made things worse.  With the stacks last update, I am loosing intersest in mathstack, reluctantly accepting it as another failed website for being too show offish and clutered.  I came to this site for  math, not for eternal commenting about this site.