# Filtering a Tag

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, search

How can I remove all questions with accepted answers from view?

Comment: I removed your second question. I don't know why you put it there, but perhaps you didn't know that [voting is different on meta](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: Also, how is this different from your [previous question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28904/ignoring-the-unneeded)?

Comment: @user1729.  I put it there to get around the automated quality control monster.

Comment: @user1729  Good, you found it where the syntax is explained.

Comment: Okay. But I don't understand your second comment.

Answer (score 3):

The search command `hasaccepted:0` does the job.

Then you can click on `Newest` or `Votes` to sort those questions.

Comment: Where is the search command in MSE?  Can I lock it in so every time I open MSE it shows up that way?

Comment: @WilliamElliot, the search box is in the top bar. The ability to pin searches to the left bar is planned, and is part of the reason for the recent redesign which added the left bar.

Comment: The  left bar is a huge waste of limited screen space that ruins the readibility of the website by shrinking and cramming too much into a confined space.  The left bar, for what little it contains, was best left at the  top of the site.

Comment: @PeterTaylor  Let me know when that pinning happens.  That might help the current visual mess of the recent change and encourage greater participation at MSE which has decreased due to the new colume as explained in my unaddressed comment.  In general MSE needs to be simplified and the point system reevaluated.